# Regex Matching Square Brackets Within Square Brackets Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, regex, google-sheets

I am currently scripting using Google Script. I'm trying to select anything that isn't the characters within the square bracket by writing:

`var cleantext = text.replace(/[^\s\w"!,、。\.?？！:]/g,'');`

I want to also keep "[" and "]" and I have followed some of the tutorials here trying "\\]" and "\\["

`var cleantext = text.replace(/[^\s\w"!,、。\.?？！:"\\]""\\["]/g,'');`

or trying \\] and \\[

`var cleantext = text.replace(/[^\s\w"!,、。\.?？！:\\]\\[]/g,'');`

Please feel free to change how my question is worded, as I am finding that I probably don't know what question I'm actually trying to ask here as there are many similar questions with similar titles already here at Stackoverflow.

I wish to edit a whole column of cells, which are a combination of Japanese, Chinese, and English characters.

For an example:
"こんにちは、私はJimです | [Audio.Category:Jim]"
would output to:
"こんにちは、私はJimです [Audio.Category:Jim]"

Deleting emojis, and other characters not defined by what's within the brackets.

Comment: Can you include input and expected result at Question?

Comment: Done, added input and expected result.

Comment: Not familiar with Google Script, but wouldn't `\[\]` do exactly what you want? i.e. `/[^\s\w"!,、。\.?？！:\[\]]/`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, that is removing the square brackets. When I click on the first square bracket with that code, it highlights the second one, as if to say they are paired.

Comment: `\[([^]]+)\]` this will get everything in the square brackets

Comment: `\w` in JavaScript regex does not match Unicode letters, so your `[^\w]` will remove all your Japanese texts.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, in Google Script, it seems to be keeping the Japanese characters just fine.

Comment: I will check again then and come back. JS  regex `\w` is not Unicode aware, and apps script uses JS regex flavor, not RE2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include `]` and `[` into a JavaScript regex character class, you need to escape `]` and you do not have to escape `[`:

```
/[abc[\]xyz]/
     ^^^
```

If you need to support ASCII letters and Japanese only, you need to add the [Japanese letter ranges](https://gist.github.com/ryanmcgrath/982242):

```
/[^\s"!,、。.?？！:[\][A-Za-z\u3000-\u303F\u3040-\u309F\u30A0-\u30FF\uFF00-\uFFEF\u4E00-\u9FAF\u2605-\u2606\u2190-\u2195\u203B]+/g
```

Here is a sample solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange('F13').getValue();
  Logger.log(cell);
  var reg_ascii_letter = "A-Za-z";
  var reg_japanese_letter = "\\u3000-\\u303F\\u3040-\\u309F\\u30A0-\\u30FF\\uFF00-\\uFFEF\\u4E00-\\u9FAF\\u2605-\\u2606\\u2190-\\u2195\\u203B";
  var rx = new RegExp("[^\\s\"!,、。.?？！:[\\][" + reg_ascii_letter + reg_japanese_letter + "]+", "g");
  Logger.log(rx);
  var nval = cell.replace(rx, '').replace(/(\s){2,}/g, '$1');
  sheet.getRange('F15').setValue(nval);
}
```

[image]

In a similar way, you may build a Unicode regex for any letter.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. This worked perfectly.